# Is there a meta text processing concept in CS?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions, natural-language-processing

I understand that text processing could be done in various ways on top of operating systems:

- **Shell utilities for processing a file (and/or a file name):** `tr`, `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, `mv` and others
- **text editors for processing a file (and/or or a file name):** `nano`, `Vim`, `Emacs` and others; whether CLUI/TUI/GUI and whether for "plain" or "rich" text
- **Possible shell builtins:** such as `compgen` to to generate auto-completion matches for specified commands and possibly others

I further understand that generally all of these programs can be empowered by what I can name "meta text processing" implementations such as regex and serialization (for example; JSON key-value pairs).

Is there a *meta text processing* concept in CS (and what might be a practical example besides regex and serialization)?

<sub>I am hoping to find theory regarding text processing, or computer data processing. I don't expect an answer such as "you could use YAML instead JSON".</sub>

Comment: Since you are asking about processing arbitrary text, the following is not entirely relevant, but in lisp-family languages (Common Lisp, Clojure, Scheme, etc.), code is written in the form of a data structure within the language, i.e. a list, which makes it easy to use the language to manipulate code or any other data that has been parsed into lists (or list of lists, etc.).  That is close to a meta text processing concept, though it can't be applied directly to arbitrary, unprocessed strings of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into Theory of Automata, Languages and Computation:
These are the theoretical foundations of *scanning, parsing and processing text* (and furthermore constructing formal languages and grammars).

Components of the theory, are, for example:

- Pushdown automaton
- Context free grammars
- Parsing techniques such as recursive decent, LL or SLR parsing.

---

Classical introductory textbook on this subject is "Introduction To Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation" by John E. Hopcroft,Rajeev Motwani and Jeffrey D.Ullman.